# How to create a checkbox in Geometry nodes modifier stack

Tags: interface, geometry-nodes, customization, custom-attributes

In the image below, I have two switch nodes. The default appearance for the boolean input of the switch node is a checkbox. But if I pull in an input to control the switch node from the modifier stack, it renders as an integer input.

Is there any way to render a checkbox in the modifier stack instead?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature parity between the modifier options panel and node groups UI is not automatic, things need to be designed and implemented separately. The good news is [checkboxes for boolean inputs for Geometry Nodes modifier panel](https://developer.blender.org/D12816) has just been implemented two days ago!

[image]

You can use them today if you're OK with [experimental daily alpha builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/), otherwise you'll need to wait for *Blender 3.5* to be officially released.

**Update after a question by OP about other layout organization tricks:**

Even if you delete their names in the N panel options, input boxes of exposed sockets stay, so unfortunately they're no good for layout purposes. However, when you delete its name, the *String* box uses the full width of the panel, so you can use that as a faux-divider. Another nice thing about it is that when you hover over a *String* text box on the panel and press *Backspace*, it resets, so you can use the *Default* text entry to make semi-permanent titles like this:

[image]

Comment: This patch is most welcome :) I'm a bit on the fence about using half of the row space to display nothing, but, oh well :p

Comment: @Gorgious It looked [like this](https://i.imgur.com/rcQhpzq.png) before they changed it so I'm a-OK with this version! :)

Comment: I just thought of a second question. Do you know if I can hide the input (whatever data type it is) and just keep the label? That would definitely help with organization of long GN modifiers if I could label individual categories.

Comment: @aphatetic_artist Even if you delete the name, their input boxes (whether it's a slider, or a number box, or a checkbox, or a dropdown menu...) stay, so no, unfortunately. However, when you delete its name, the String box uses the full width so you can use it as a faux-divider. That's what I usually do. Another nice thing about it: when you hover over them and press Backspace, they reset to their default, so you can use the Default entry to make almost-permanent titles: https://i.imgur.com/bEXo5Cn.png

Comment: love it, thank you